# how to find whether the a particular date lies between two dates from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
<?php

 $hostname = "localhost";
 $db_user = "root";  
 $db_password = "";  
 $database = "rentcar";  
 $db_table = "reservation"; 

 $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password); 

 mysql_select_db($database,$db);

 $date1 = $_POST['datepicker1'];

 $date2 = $_POST['datepicker2'];


 $start_date = strtotime($date1);

 $end_date = strtotime($date2);

 $query  =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE  ('pudate'>".$start_date." AND         
 'dodate'<".$end_date.") OR ('pudate'<".$start_date." AND 'dodate'>".$end_date." ) OR 
  ('pudate'<".$end_date." AND 'dodate'>".$end_date.") OR ('pudate'<".$start_date." AND 
  'dodate'>".$start_date." )");

 $result = mysql_query($query); 

  if ($result) 

 {
   echo "vehicle is available";
 }

 else
 {
 echo "vehicle is not available";    

  }

 ?>
```

the pudate and dodate are the dates in the database.
When i try to run it always show me the output as vehicle is not available. I m running the query st check whether the car is already booked between two these days if the car is already booked it will say the car is not available but no matter how i try to run the query it always give me the same result.

Comment: Can you explain in real-world terms how those serious of WHERE conditions are supposed to operate? Also, might want to get in the habit of writing your queries so they are more easily readable in code.

Comment: it will check that if my pick up date is in between the start date and end date or my drop off date is in between the start date and end date it will show that the car is not available otherwise if they are not than it will show the car is available

Answer (score 0):

You failed to pick up the actual result of the query. Actually, you are call `mysql_query()` twice (which returns a **handle**). In your case, use `mysql_num_rows()` to fetch the amount of rows, which should tell you if the vehicle is available or not.

Comment: than its showing me the following error  mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\rentcar\search_result.php on line 40

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not correctly processing the results of your query.  To fix this, you can try something like this:

```
$result =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE  ('pudate'>".$start_date." AND         
  'dodate'<".$end_date.") OR ('pudate'<".$start_date." AND 'dodate'>".$end_date." ) OR 
  ('pudate'<".$end_date." AND 'dodate'>".$end_date.") OR ('pudate'<".$start_date." AND 
  'dodate'>".$start_date." )");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    //$row contains the results of your query  
}
```